# Vuejs component props as string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to pass this prop as a string:

```
<list-view :avatar="pictures"></list-view>
```

But I think Vue thinks I am trying to call a method because I am getting these warnings:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "pictures" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "avatar". Expected String, got Undefined.

How can I pass `"pictures"` as a string?

```js
Vue.component('list-view', {
  props: {
    avatar: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  template: `<div>{{ avatar }}</div>`,
});

var app = new Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <list-view :avatar="pictures" ></list-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Right now, Vue is trying to find a variable named `pictures` to pass as the property value to the child component.

If you want to specify a string value in that inline expression, you can wrap the value in quotes to make it a string:

```
<list-view :avatar="'pictures'"></list-view>
```

---

Alternately, as @Zunnii answered below, if the value being passed is really just a static string, you can simply omit the `v-bind` colon shorthand:

```
<list-view avatar="pictures"></list-view>
```

This way, the `avatar` prop of the child component will be assigned the string value `"pictures"`.

Answer (score 17):

If you really want to pass static string, you can just pass string directly without v-bind

```
<div id="app">
   <greeting text="world"></greeting>
</div>
```

then in JS file

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
    props: ['text'],
  template: '<h1>Hello {{ text  }}!</h1>'
});


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

JSFiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/dpLp4jk8/

Answer (score 1):

```
:avatar="pictures"  //vue treat pictures as a variable or computed properties
```

By default vue treat pictures as a variable or computed properties and vue search locally and doesn't find and throw an error. So what you have to do is tell vue externally that it is a string not a variable or computed properties. So enclose in quotes.

```
:avatar="'pictures'" // I guess it will work
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel we can pass string as shown below

```
function authUserCurrency(){
    return '$';
}
<service :authusercurrency="'{!!authUserCurrency()!!}'"></services>
```

**Vue.js Template**

```
props:{authusercurrency:String},
```

**OR**

```
 props:['authUserCurrency'],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to pass static string along with dynamic property value.
So did as below.

```
<home-card :title="'By' + post.author.name "></home-card>
```