# How to pass pug variables into vue dynamic attributes?

Tags: vuejs2, pug

The problem is that I can't pass dynamic Pug variables to Vue component via attributes, if they're of "String" type. Vue considers the string that I'm trying to pass as a name of Vue property.

**The problem**

*template.pug*

```
- var pugVariable = 'John';

my-component(v-bind:name= pugVariable)
```

*MyComponent.Vue*

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }  
  }
}
```

I get an error: "Property or method "John" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.", which means, as far as I understand, that Vue considers string that is in `pugVariable` as a name of Vue property.

**The question**

So, the question is: now to persuade Vue to treat this variable as a string?

**What I've already tried:**

I tried to pass an object literal instead of string, as follows:

```
my-component(v-bind:name= {value: pugVariable})
```

It works, but we lose the ability to check the type of passed value, so I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an answer earlier that whoever:)

As described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45175556/7473709, in case if we want just to pass static string, we have to simply get rid of `v-bind:` prefix, so it looks like as follows:

```
my-component(name= {value: pugVariable})
```