# How to use props and watch in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am a beginner with VueJS and I use vue-chessboard library for my project. But I am so confuse about the way to use of the library, I see that when we use showThreats, then we can use ":showThreats", but we do not use ":" for "orientation". There are code of vue-chessboard:

vue-chessboard

```
export default {
  name: 'chessboard',
  props: {
    ...,
    showThreats: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    onPromotion: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => 'q',
    },
    orientation: {
      type: String,
      default: 'white',
    },
  },
  watch: {
    fen: function (newFen) {
      this.fen = newFen
      this.loadPosition()
    },
    orientation: function (orientation) {
      console.log('watch orientation________', orientation)
      this.orientation = orientation
      this.loadPosition()
    },
    showThreats: function (st) {
      this.showThreats = st
      if (this.showThreats) {
        this.paintThreats()
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {...
  }
}
```

when I use this library

```
<chessboard :orientation="black"/>
```

Then the browser will notice:
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "black" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
And there is no happen if I use:

```
<chessboard orientation="black"/>
```

But with the showThreats, the document give that:

```
<chessboard :showThreats="true"/>
```

I can not understand why? Thank you for helping me ^^

Comment: The difference with ```:``` is that one binds to a value and the other doesn't. in ```orientation="black"``` you don't need ```:``` because all you do is pass a **string**. In your second scenario ```:showThreats="true"``` you need ```:``` because you are passing a **javascript boolean**

Comment: aha, I see the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175527/vuejs-component-props-as-string?rq=

Comment: Using a colon in front of an attribute is equivalent to `v-bind`. That means that an attribute, like `:orientation="black"` is binding the orientation attribute to the variable `black`, but if you use `orientation="black"`, then you are just binding orientation to the string `black`

Answer (score 0):

When you use :some-property, that is a shorthand for v-bind:some-property which means it will bind a variable to that component from parent (two way data binding which is explained in documentation). When you use it without ":" it will only pass a string to that component. So when you pass :orientation="black" it expects that you have variable named black inside parent component. If You write :orientation="'black'" in that case it would only pass a string, but it is easier to write just orientation="black".